# Ajax проверка логина в базе данных

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Есть форма, после заполнения и отправки полей формы  на сервер данные записываются в базу данных. А я хочу на лету проверять поля формы при заполнении — есть ли они уже в базе, или таких нет.

Как мне проверять эти записи?

файл php:

```
<?php
$user = 'root';
$pass = '8169x5it';
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=reg_form', $user, $pass); 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM WebsiteUsers";
$query = $db->prepare($sql);
$query -> execute();

$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //получить асоциативный масив
?>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Password</th>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
    </tr>
<?php


foreach ($result as $row) {
    echo "<tr><td>";
    echo $row['userName'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['pass'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['fullName'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>";
    echo $row['email'];
    echo "</td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}


?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Если нужно проверять при заполнении формы, то ключевое слово тут: `ajax`. Алгоритм действий такой:

**1. страница с формой**

1. отключаем действие формы `onsubmit="return false;"`.
2. на событие обновления формы вешаем функцию js, с помощью которой собираем состояние элементов формы и генерируем ajax-запрос к файлу из п.2
3. на событие отправки формы вешаем js функцию, генерирующую запрос к файлу, который должен принять результаты отправки формы (параметр `action` для формы не нужен)

**2. скрипт php, для проверки логина**

1. принимает post-данные и делает запрос к БД.
2. если пользователь существует, возвращаем `echo 1`, если нет - `echo 0`

**3. на страницу из п.1 возвращается ответ ajax (0 или 1)**, на основании чего мы что-то сообщаем пользователю.

Это если в теории, без подробностей реализации.

Answer (score 0):

Либо проверяй отдельным запросом по нужным полям, либо добавь уникальный ключ (составной по нужным полям) и вставляй посредством `INSERT IGNORE INTO...`
Проверить вставилось или было проигнорировано: `mysql_affected_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть очень много уже готовых скриптов которые проверяют есть ли такой пользователь в базе данных например:

[Live username Ajax jQuery PHP](http://www.infotuts.com/live-username-availability-checker-and-password-strength-indicator-with-jquery-and-ajax/)

[Демо 1](http://www.infotuts.com/demo/username-checker-password-indicator/)

Первый проверяет в базе по каждой букве, а второй только тогда когда пользователь написал логин полностью и перешел к заполнения другого поля

[Live Username Availability Check using PHP and jQuery AJAX](http://phppot.com/jquery/live-username-availability-check-using-php-and-jquery-ajax/#tutorial-menu)

[Демо 2](http://phppot.com/demo/live-username-availability-check-using-php-and-jquery-ajax/)

А если не нравится ни один и этих скриптов просто вбей в яндексе **live username availability check**

Успехов.